# Access iframe content on same domain

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I'm trying to create a simple test to modify the content of an iframe from its parent container and to modify the content of the parent container from the iframe. Here's what I have so far:

first.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>First</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="shared.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="first.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>First</h1>
    <iframe src="http://localhost:3000/second.html"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

second.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Second</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="shared.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="second.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Second</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

shared.js:

```
function modifyContent(targetContainerElement, targetSelector, sourceString) {
  $(targetContainerElement).find(targetSelector).html("Modified by " + sourceString + "!");
}
```

first.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var iframe = $("iframe");
  modifyContent(iframe.contents(), "h1", "First");
});
```

second.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  if (!top.document)
    return;

  modifyContent(top.document.body, "h1", "Second");
});
```

To run the code, I use `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 3000` and navigate to `localhost:3000/first.html`. The first header is modified and says "Modified by Second!" but the second header just says "Second". What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the h1 tag inside the iframe when it's completely loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var iframe = $("iframe");
  iframe.load(function ()
  {
    modifyContent(iframe.contents(), "h1", "First");
  });
});
```

Plus I think you should rewrite `modifyContent` :

```
function modifyContent(isJquery, targetContainerElement, targetSelector, sourceString) 
{
  if ( isJquery )
    targetContainerElement.find(targetSelector).html("Modified by " + sourceString + "!");
  else
    $(targetContainerElement).find(targetSelector).html("Modified by " + sourceString + "!");
}
```

just `targetContainerElement` would work cause you don't really need to wrap it in $() since it's already a jquery object

Comment: It's not a jQuery object in second.js.

Comment: Rewrote my code for both scenarios. Just pass additional parameter isJquery if the element is a jQuery object

Comment: Are the page and the iframe from the same domain?

Comment: Yes. It's all in the question. In fact, it's in the title.

Comment: What happens if you just run $("iframe").contents().find('h1').html('test') from the main page?

Comment: Are you sure that by the time you're trying to change the h1 tag the content in the iframe is actually loaded? Try changing the h1 tag inside $("iframe").load(function (){ //code });

Comment: Fantastic! I didn't even think about that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ah wonderful, the document.ready gets me every time, all works now!